# How to mock a dependency in Jest / Typescript

Tags: typescript, jestjs

I'm using Jest to test some TypeScript code that looks like this:

```
export class ClassUnderTest {
  readonly foo: Foo

  constructor() {
    this.foo = new Foo()
  }

  methodToTest() { /* code here that doesn't use foo */ }
}
```

Foo is a class that is part of a module that is loaded at runtime. I don't have access to it. Another member of the team added a type definition for Foo so that we don't get compilation errors:

```
// types/foo.d.ts
declare global {
  class Foo { /* method signatures follow */ }
}
```

In my Jest tests, I get the error: `ReferenceError: Foo is not defined`.

How should I go about mocking or doing something else that would allow me to test method `ClassUnderTest.methodToTest()`?

Comment: If `ClassUnderTest` weren't so dependent on `Foo`, e.g. the dependency was inverted, you could easily inject an appropriate test double (for example, given that the value isn't being used in the method you're testing, `null`).